# parsing a line into a dictionary through a list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to slice different parts of a line into a list of dictionaries using a list comprehension. The code below doesn't work, but it illustrates what I am trying to do.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

```
def getDataElements(self):
    return [x for x for line in self.data: {"Number": line[0:9],
            "FullName": line[9:27].rstrip(),
            "LastName": line[27:63].rstrip(),
            "Area": line[63:65].rstrip(),
            "City": line[65:90].rstrip(),
            "Status": line[91],
            "Status2": line[92],
            "Status3": line[93]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instances where list comprehensions are good, but this is not one of them. Just use a loop and a generator:

```
for line in self.data:
    yield {
        "Number": line[0:9],
        "FullName": line[9:27].rstrip(),
        "LastName": line[27:63].rstrip(),
        "Area": line[63:65].rstrip(),
        "City": line[65:90].rstrip(),
        "Status": line[91],
        "Status2": line[92],
        "Status3": line[93]
    }
```

If you absolutely need to return a list, pass the output through `list()`:

```
output_list = list(self.getDataElements())
```

If you're not comfortable with that, there's always the append-to-a-list way:

```
people = []

for line in self.data:
    people.append({
        "Number": line[0:9],
        "FullName": line[9:27].rstrip(),
        "LastName": line[27:63].rstrip(),
        "Area": line[63:65].rstrip(),
        "City": line[65:90].rstrip(),
        "Status": line[91],
        "Status2": line[92],
        "Status3": line[93]
    })

return people
```

Answer (score 2):

You were somewhat clear, but you have to put the dictionary in the beginning...if I fully understand what you want, the following should work:

```
return [{"Number": line[0:9],"FullName": line[9:27].rstrip(),"LastName": line[27:63].rstrip(),"Area": line[63:65].rstrip(),"City": line[65:90].rstrip(),"Status": line[91],"Status2": line[92],"Status3": line[93]} for line in self.data]
```

unless there is some extra level of nesting because you say `x for x for line` yet you don't use `x` so I ignored it in that manner. Let me know if that was incorrect, and if so explain in a bit more detail please!

Answer (score 1):

First write a function that parses a `line` and returns the corresponding dict:

```
def parseDataLine(self, line):
    return { ... }   # Same as your parsing code.
```

The rest of your code would be like this:

```
def getDataElements(self):
    return [self.parseDataLine(line) for line in self.data]
```

This type of approach keeps everything very readable and simple.